Boot Delays on PowerPC Board with RTC Clock and hwclock --hctosys Command Related to Kernel Configurations
I am working on a PowerPC board using kernel version 4.1.35 and encountering significant boot delays, specifically around the RTC clock (ds-1337) operations. During the boot process, a script (hwclock.sh) runs the hwclock --hctosys command, and I've added print statements to log its execution time in the kernel logs.
Here’s a snippet from hwclock.sh:
echo "running command hwclock --hctosys. - arij" | tee /dev/kmsg
hwclock $tz --hctosys
echo "ending hwclock --hctosys. - arij" | tee /dev/kmsg

When the kernel configuration CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG is disabled, the hwclock command experiences significant delays, sometimes up to 50 seconds. However, when CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG is enabled, the delays are significantly reduced, with execution times ranging between 4 to 12 seconds.
Here are some kernel log snippets from various boot cycles with CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG disabled:
Boot cycle 1:
[    6.401707] running command hwclock --hctosys. - arij
[   39.206200] ending hwclock --hctosys. - arij

Boot cycle 2:
[    7.054404] running command hwclock --hctosys. - arij
[   14.218021] ending hwclock --hctosys. - arij

Boot cycle 5:
[   18.659482] running command hwclock --hctosys. - arij
[   50.005113] ending hwclock --hctosys. - arij

With CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG enabled, the delays decrease:
Example with **CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG **enabled:
[   8.833980] running command hwclock --hctosys. - arij
[  14.223970] ending hwclock --hctosys. - arij

Additionally, when booting with the configuration CONFIG_PROFILING enabled, the hwclock command consistently takes no more than 2 seconds.
Questions

What could be causing the drastic increase in boot time when CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG is disabled?
Why does enabling CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG reduce the time taken for the hwclock --hctosys command?
Could there be any underlying issues with the RTC driver or interactions between the hwclock command and kernel configurations?
How might CONFIG_PROFILING impact the timing of hwclock --hctosys?
Any insights into these behaviors would be greatly appreciated.

Update 1:
i have tried multiple kernel prints in the rtc drivers and it only showed that the mutex lock is waiting to be acquired. i cant understand whats causing the problem and how is it not appearing when dynamic debugging is enabled
the prints i enabled are like this:
pr_info("---------------------  %s: %s: Line %d - Mutex Locking interruptible - arij\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
int err = mutex_lock_interruptible(&rtc->ops_lock);
pr_info("---------------------  %s: %s: Line %d - Mutex Locked interruptible - arij\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);

and got prints:
[   17.450075]  running command hwclock  --hctosys. - arij
[   17.461239] rtc_core: ---------------------  /home/pc/kernel-source/drivers/rtc/rtc-dev.c: rtc_dev_ioctl: Line 234 - Mutex locking- arij
[   23.737863] rtc_core: ---------------------  /home/pc/kernel-source/drivers/rtc/rtc-dev.c: rtc_dev_ioctl: Line 236 - Mutex locked with cmd=1076129801 - arij
[   23.752437] ---------------------  /home/pc/kernel-source/drivers/rtc/interface.c: rtc_read_time: Line 62 - Mutex Locking interruptible - arij
[   27.005861] ---------------------  /home/pc/kernel-source/drivers/rtc/interface.c: rtc_read_time: Line 65 - Mutex Locked interruptible - arij
[   27.020196] ---------------------  /home/pc/kernel-source/drivers/rtc/interface.c: rtc_read_time: Line 74 - Mutex Unlock interruptible - arij
[   27.034029] rtc_core: ---------------------  /home/pc/kernel-source/drivers/rtc/rtc-dev.c: rtc_dev_ioctl: Line 234 - Mutex locking- arij
[   30.637859] rtc_core: ---------------------  /home/pc/kernel-source/drivers/rtc/rtc-dev.c: rtc_dev_ioctl: Line 236 - Mutex locked with cmd=536899588 - arij
[   30.652312] ---------------------  /home/pc/kernel-source/drivers/rtc/interface.c: rtc_update_irq_enable: Line 515 - Mutex Locking interruptible - arij
[   34.805855] ---------------------  /home/pc/kernel-source/drivers/rtc/interface.c: rtc_update_irq_enable: Line 517 - Mutex Locked interruptible - arij
[   34.819887] ---------------------  /home/pc/kernel-source/drivers/rtc/interface.c: rtc_update_irq_enable: Line 552 - Mutex unock in out: - arij
[   34.833291] ---------------------  /home/pc/kernel-source/drivers/rtc/interface.c: rtc_update_irq_enable: Line 515 - Mutex Locking interruptible - arij
[   62.173853] ---------------------  /home/pc/kernel-source/drivers/rtc/interface.c: rtc_update_irq_enable: Line 517 - Mutex Locked interruptible - arij
[   62.187884] ---------------------  /home/pc/kernel-source/drivers/rtc/interface.c: rtc_update_irq_enable: Line 552 - Mutex unock in out: - arij
[   62.204506]  ending hwclock  --hctosys. - arij

Update 2:
I also changed the configuration to not get a timeless kernel. but i still observed the same delays
CONFIG_HZ_PERIODIC=y
CONFIG_NO_HZ_IDLE not set
CONFIG_NO_HZ not set


Do you have an interrupt line from the RTC to the SoC? If not, is RTC_INTF_DEV_UIE_EMUL enabled?

hi @AlexandreBelloni  the RTC has a SQWINT pin but it is not connected to the SoC. and the configuration RTC_INTF_DEV_UIE_EMUL  is disabled

Then enabling RTC_INTF_DEV_UIE_EMUL should reduce the boot time, there is anther solution to your issue but you'd have to upgrade to a newer kernel;

yes okay thank you so much. there was a delay even after enabling this option but i do understand where the problem is.
